# SpringBoot 1.4.x compatibility with Java 11

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Is SpringBoot 1.4.x compatible with Java 11? I can see the minimum JRE requirements for SpringBoot, but no notes for higher versions. Java 9 had significant changes, so there might be a possibility of breaking with old spring versions.

Our complete maven project runs on SpringBoot 1.4.x (i know it's outdated) with java 8. We are planning on atleast running new modules on Java 11. And migrate the complete project to SpringBoot 2.x later point of time.

Comment: Current version is 2.4.5. Upgrade immediately. No one should use 1.x anymore.

Comment: I see the recommended practice is to update spring-boot. But it's a slow transformation for us. Just wanted to know if someone has already tried and hit a road blocker.